# Retrieve All Members of Large AD Groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Working with an Microsoft Active Directory and Unboundid SDK and there is a group with >29k members.

I am trying to utilize the range values to get all the groups, but can not determine when the end has been reached.

I am using this method: (Updated to working code)

```
  public static List<String> getAttributeRangeBasedSearch(LDAPConnection ldc, String basedn, String filter, int step, String return_attribute) throws LDAPException
{
List<String> allValues = new ArrayList<String>();
// initialize counter to total the group members and range values
int allvalues = 0;
int start = 0;
// int step = 1000;
int finish = step - 1;
boolean finallyFinished = false;
String range;
// loop through the query until we have all the results
while (!finallyFinished)
{
    range = start + "-" + finish;
    String currentRange = return_attribute + ";Range=" + range;
    String range_returnedAtts[] = { currentRange };
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(basedn, SearchScope.BASE, filter, range_returnedAtts);
    List<SearchResultEntry> rangedEntries = ldc.search(searchRequest).getSearchEntries();
    for (Iterator<SearchResultEntry> iterator = rangedEntries.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
    {
    SearchResultEntry searchResultEntry = iterator.next();
    Collection<Attribute> allAttribute = searchResultEntry.getAttributes();
    for (Iterator<Attribute> attributeIterator = allAttribute.iterator(); attributeIterator.hasNext();)
    {
        Attribute attribute = attributeIterator.next();
        log.debug("---> " + allvalues + ": " + attribute.getName());
        if (attribute.getName().endsWith("*"))
        {
        currentRange = attribute.getName();
        finallyFinished = true;
        }
        String[] attributeBatch = searchResultEntry.getAttributeValues(currentRange);
        for (int i = 0; i < attributeBatch.length; i++)
        {
        allValues.add(attributeBatch[i]);
        log.debug("-- " + allvalues++ + " " + attribute.getName() + ":" + attributeBatch[i]);
        }
    }

    }// for SearchResultEntry
    start = start + step;
    finish = finish + step;
}// finallyFinished
return allValues;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks
-jim

Comment: AD, by default, only stores maximum of 5000 entries per attribute; if there are more the attribute is split into several "chunks" - `member0-4999;` `member5000-9999;` etc. Can you just merge these together to get the full list? Optionally, you can do a paged search asking for all users whose memberOf attribute contains the distinguished name of your group, but this would be slower compared to the former method.

Comment: The problem is not the entries but rather values determined by the MaxValRange which is for this instance 1,500 for each attribute. I am getting all the results but when I ask for the last set of values, it is a partial size like member28131-????? to some value I have no idea what. So how to I tell the returned value of the range within each result. Thanks -jim

Comment: Actually now I remember that the semicolon is exactly after the attribute name, so just loop through all retrieved attributes, split their names on the semicolon and merge any identically named attributes together.

Comment: So I got it working, but this is so udgy and not anything within the LDAP Standards. Anyone know how to use the "reported" control as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223322.aspx ?

Answer (score 2):

I got things working, but the process is very difficult and  currently I am using a hard coded value for the step as this could be dynamically changed formt he default of 1,500 to a hard coded limit of 5,000.

I have not been able to determine the value dynamically. [Appears, maybe,](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=315071) that if it is not defined at: CN=Query-Policies,CN=Directory Service,CN=Windows NT,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,forest root then is must be at defaults, which the default, also varies based on which version of Microsoft Active Directory is being used.

There is also described in MSDN about [some sort of control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223322.aspx) that might help, but no information on how it could be used. **Anyone ever use this?**

LDAP policies are specified using the lDAPAdminLimits attribute.

The lDAPAdminLimits attribute of a queryPolicy object is a multivalued string where each string value encodes a name-value pair. In the encoding, the name and value are separated by an "=". For example, the encoding of the name "MaxActiveQueries" with value "0" is "MaxActiveQueries=0". Each name is the name of an LDAP policy, and the value is a value of that policy.
There can be multiple queryPolicy objects in a AD Forest. A DC determines the queryPolicy object that contains its policies according to the following logic:

- If the queryPolicyObject attribute is present on the DC's nTDSDSA object, the DC uses the queryPolicy object referenced by it.
- Otherwise, if the queryPolicyObject attribute is present on the nTDSSiteSettings object for the Active Directory Site to which the DC belongs, the DC uses the queryPolicy object referenced by the Active Directory Site.
- Otherwise, the DC uses the queryPolicy object whose DN is "CN=Default Query Policy,CN=Query-Policies" relative to the nTDSService object (for example, "CN=Default Query Policy, CN=Query-Policies, CN=Directory Service, CN=Windows NT, CN=Services" relative to the root of the config NC).

Comment: This DN is correct. For ADLDS, the DN is `CN=Default Query Policy,CN=Query-Policies,CN=Directory Service,CN=Windows NT,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,CN=xxxxxxxxxxx`. Attribute is `lDAPAdminLimits` with the value `MaxValRange=5000`. The number is adjustable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very good code example where you can get all members of a group by ranges. It handles the case when you're on the last range too. You can also transform this method in a paginated request. Have a look. It helped me.

```
try
{
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=My Distribution List,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com");
    DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
    searcher.Filter = "(objectClass=*)";

    uint rangeStep = 1000;
    uint rangeLow = 0;
    uint rangeHigh = rangeLow + (rangeStep - 1);
    bool lastQuery = false;
    bool quitLoop = false;

    do
    {
        string attributeWithRange;
        if(!lastQuery)
        {
            attributeWithRange = String.Format("member;range={0}-{1}", rangeLow, rangeHigh);
    }
        else
        {
            attributeWithRange = String.Format("member;range={0}-*", rangeLow);
    }        
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Clear();
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attributeWithRange);
        SearchResult results = searcher.FindOne();
        foreach(string res in results.Properties.PropertyNames)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(res.ToString());
    }
        if(results.Properties.Contains(attributeWithRange))
        {
            foreach(object obj in results.Properties[attributeWithRange])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType());
                if(obj.GetType().Equals(typeof(System.String)))
                {
            }
                else if (obj.GetType().Equals(typeof(System.Int32)))
                {
            }
                Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
        }
            if(lastQuery)
            {
                quitLoop = true;
        }
    }
        else
        {
            lastQuery = true;
    }
        if(!lastQuery)
        {
            rangeLow = rangeHigh + 1;
            rangeHigh = rangeLow + (rangeStep - 1);
    }
}
    while(!quitLoop);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Handle exception ex.
}
```

Source: http://systemmanager.ru/adam-sdk.en/netds/enumerating_members_in_a_large_group.htm

Answer (score 1):

This one can retrieve and store in textfile any number of users. Moreover it will not finish in infinite loop if group is empty

```
$myGroup = [string]$args[0];
$myGroup = $myGroup.replace(" ",",");
$group = [adsi]("LDAP://$($myGroup)");
$from = 0 
$all = $false 

$members = @() 


while (! $all) { 
   trap{$script:all = $True;continue} 
   $to = $from + 999 
   $DS = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($Group,"(objectClass=*)","member;range=$from-$to",'Base') 
   $members += $ds.findall() | foreach {$_.properties | foreach {$_.item($_.PropertyNames -like 'member;*')}} 
   if($from -gt $members.count){
      break;
   }
   $from += 1000 
} 

$currentExecuting = (Get-Item $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
$group.sAMAccountName
$members | measure-object 

$members > "$($currentExecuting.Directory)\$($group.sAMAccountName).txt"
```

usage:

```
getADGroupMembers.ps1 CN=groupName,OU=myOrgUnit,DC=contoso,DC=com
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting all group members was also a challange to me. By testing the AD searcher I found that when the max range was exceeded, the max range was a number in the result. Otherwise the result show * as max range.
So that gave me the opportunity to dynamically use the range during runtime.
Here is the powershell code that works for me.
Beware: some groups like "Domain Users" or "Domain Computers" will not work. I assume as all users/computers are member by default.

```
function Get-RpAdGroupMember{
    <#
        .synopsis
            Get members of AD group
    
        .description
            Get members of AD groups when Get-AdGroupMember failed due to too many members.
            The range of the chunks are detemined automatically.
            The output are the distinguished names of the members.

            Beware: some AD groups like "Domain Users" or "Domain Computers" do not work as all user or computer are members by default

        .parameter GroupName
            the name of the group as sAMAccountName of distinguished name

        .example
            Get-RpAdGroupMember -GroupName MyGroupName

            # use the sAMAccountName of the group
            # the distinguished name will be used from the result of internally used Get-AdGroup from ActiveDirectory Powershell module.

        .example
            Get-RpAdGroupMember -GroupName "CN=MyGroupName,OU=someOU,DC=exmaple,DC=com"

            # use the distiguished name of the group
            
    #>
        [CmdletBinding()]
        Param(
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$GroupName
        
        )
    
        try{
            
            Write-Verbose -Message "working on $($GroupName)"

            # if the group do not start with CN= the get the group from AD
            if(-not $GroupName.StartsWith("CN=")){
                $GroupNameDN = (Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(samaccountname=$($GroupName))").DistinguishedName
            }
            else{
                $GroupNameDN = $GroupName
            }

            # get the object from AD
            $adGroup = [adsi]("LDAP://$($GroupNameDN)")
    
            # find an object?
            if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($adGroup.name)){
                throw "Object not found: $($GroupName)"
            }
    
            # create an instance of the searcher
            $searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.directorySearcher($adGroup)
    
            # set the filter for the objectClass to search / we only accespt group
            $searcher.Filter = "(objectClass=group)"
        
            # initially set the max range to * and the min range to 0
            $maxRange = "*"
            $minRange = "0"
                
            do{
                
                # set the range
                $attributeWithRange = "member;range={0}-{1}" -f  $minRange,$maxRange
    
                # clear the searchers properties to load
                $null = $searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Clear()
    
                # add the properties to the searcher
                $null = $searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($attributeWithRange)
    
                # only the one group has to be searched, so use .FindOne()
                $results = $searcher.FindOne()
    
                # adspath is alway given back as propertyname. Thus if we only find one element, the group has no members
                if($results.Properties.PropertyNames.count -gt 1){
    
                    # iterate the propertynames
                    foreach($pName in $results.Properties.PropertyNames){
                            
                        # check if property Name starts with member
                        if($pName.startswith("member;")){

                            Write-Verbose -Message $pName
                            
                            # write the output base on the found property name
                            Write-Output -InputObject $results.Properties[$pName]

                            # get the max range from the result
                            $maxRange = $pName.split(";")[1].split("=")[1].split("-")[1]
                            Write-Verbose -Message "max range of $($maxRange) found"

                            # check the max range
                            if($maxRange -ne "*"){
                                
                                # if the max range is not * we do have an additional range to get
                                $minRange = [int]$maxRange + 1
                                $maxRange = "*"

                                write-verbose -Message "next iteration with min range of $($minRange)"

                            }
                            else{
                                
                                Write-Verbose -Message "this was the last iteration because max range in the result is *"
                                # the range is * means we have all members found. Set minRange to * to get out of the while loop
                                $minRange = $maxRange
                            }
    
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                else{
                
                    Write-Verbose -Message "No members in object $($GroupName)"
    
                    # no members found at all. Set minRange to * to get out of the while loop
                    $minRange = "*"
                
                }
            }
            while($minRange -ne "*")
        }
        catch{
            write-verbose -message $_.Exception.Message
            throw $_.Exception.Message
        }
    
    }
```

usage:

```
Get-RpAdGroupMember -GroupName MyGroupName
Get-RpAdGroupMember -GroupName "CN=MyGroupName,OU=someOU,DC=exmaple,DC=com"
```