# LDAP server sizelimit was exceeded ( MSAD ) with ldaps_search

Tags: active-directory, sas, ldap

Using

```sas
call ldaps_search(handle,shandle,filter, attrs, num, rc);
```

with Microsoft Active Directory I get `WARNING: LDAP server sizelimit was exceeded.`

Is there a way to page through somehow in SAS ?

I have tried `ldaps_setOptions` with `sizeLimit=2000` for example but still generates the warning, as I guess is set on Microsoft side.

Sample:

```sas
more = 1;
do while (more eq 1);
    call ldaps_search_page(handle, shandle, filter, attrs, num, rc, more, 1000);
    if rc ne 0 then do;
        more = 0;
        msg = sysmsg();
        put msg;
    end;
    /* free search results page */
    if shandle NE 0 then do;
        call ldaps_free(shandle,rc);
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to control LDAP server sizelimit from the client side (see AD's [`MaxPageSize`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315071/how-to-view-and-set-ldap-policy-in-active-directory-by-using-ntdsutil)), but yes you can still work around this via [paging controls](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Simple%20Paged%20Results%20Control).

The idea is to request a paged result set, with a number of entries per page less than server's MaxPageSize limit.

SAS provides the `call ldaps_search_page` routine that returns only a single page for a given search request and requires subsequent calls to retrieve the entirety of the results :

```sas
CALL LDAPS_SEARCH_PAGE(lHandle, sHandle, filter, attr, num, rc, more <, pageSize>);
```

> **pageSize** (optional) specifies a positive integer value, which is the number of
> results on a page of output. By default, this value is set to 50. If
> pageSize is 0, this function acts as if paging is turned off. This
> argument is case-insensitive.

For example if a query matches *n* results (exceeding server side limit) and the page size is set to 50, you need to make up to `ceil(n/50)` calls.

Here is an example taken from the doc, it uses the `more` argument in a loop to continue retrieving paged results until there is no more information to retrieve :

```sas
more = 1;
do while (more eq 1);
    call ldaps_search_page(handle, shandle, filter, attrs, num, rc, more, 50);
    ...
    /* free search results page */
    if shandle NE 0 then do;
        call ldaps_free(shandle,rc);
    end;
end;
```

https://documentation.sas.com/api/docsets/itechdsref/9.4/content/itechdsref.pdf

---

For those having trouble with `more` stuck at 1 thus causing the code above to loop forever (I don't know why the reference wouldn't get updated but OP was in this situation), actually you don't need it, incrementing a counter until the number of fetched entries reaches *num* should do the trick.

Comment: hi, tried with your suggestion ( added sample code to question above ), but more still stays as 1, so never exits the loop ?

Comment: Well.. it stays at 1 like forever ? It should depend on num such as num/pageSize yields the number of subsequent calls to perform until more equals 0 (it should be passed as a reference). What are logs saying ? Did you check that paging controls are actually working (without relying on SAS, see AD config directly or ldapsearch using -E option) ?

Comment: tried dsquery and paging working fine, just steped through the code in the debugger, on a test OU that i know has 404 objects, if i set the limit to 100 and run i can see shandle increase and num returning 4 lots or 100 and one lot or 4, but more remains 1 then on the 6th do it seems to restart and i get 4 100 and 1 4 again for ever. so it looks like th paging is working but just not update more to not 1? Thanks

Comment: Yes it's weird.. if more doesn't get updated just increment a counter until the number of fetched entries reaches *num*.

Comment: coolio, i set num to 1000 before the do, then set do while num = 1000 then when the final results come in num <> 1000 anymore and exits the do :)

Comment: What if the number of attributes with a certain name _(in my case members of a group)_ exceeds the limit? Can you page in attributes too?

Comment: @DirkHorsten yes, sort of, it's called [Attribute Range Retrieval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/attribute-range-retrieval), you need to specify a _range_ via the attribute name directly, ie. instead of using the `member` attribute, use `member;range=<low range>-<high range>`. Fetch the member attribute first to get the count, and if it exceeds the limit, then make "range queries" as needed. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710775 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355213.

Comment: Thans @EricLavault. It is years ago I programmed in Java, but I should be capable of translating your sollution to SAS, if it is possible at all.